# Python: Performance between readline and readlines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the generally difference between readlines and readline of file object. But Im more curious how their performance differ from each other, thus I made a test here.

```
import timeit

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join("Just a test case\tJust a test case2\tJust a test case3" for i in range(1000000)))

def a1():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for text in f.readlines():
            pass
def a2():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.readline()
        while text:
            text = f.readline()


print(timeit.timeit(a1, number =100))
print(timeit.timeit(a2, number =100))
```

```
$python readline_vs_readlines.py
38.410646996984724
35.876863296027295
```

But Why is that? I think io is more time consuming so if you read more times instead of read it into the memory in once, it takes more time. So from what im seeing here, why we use `readlines` anyway? It costs us enormous amount of memory if file is large with no gain on speed?

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop in the first test?  The file has already been read.

Comment: It's just for fair-ground as ```while``` loops is getting reassignment per line, I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually even slower when `readline` was used in `for` loop:

```
import timeit

with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp:
    print(*("Just a test case" for i in range(1000000)), sep='\n', file=fp)


def a1():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for _ in f.readlines():
            pass


def a2():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        while _ := f.readline():
            pass


def a3():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for _ in iter(f.readline, ''):
            pass


print(timeit.timeit(a1, number=50))
print(timeit.timeit(a2, number=50))
print(timeit.timeit(a3, number=50))
```

output:

```
10.9471131
10.282239
9.3618919
```

When comparing on same `for` loop, Clearly `a3` way is faster than `a1`, although it's aganist Zen of python.

---

Reason for this lies in source code `_pyio.py` and `iobase.c`:

When `iobase.c` is unavailable pure-python `_pyio.py` will be used.

```
def readlines(self, hint=None):
    """Return a list of lines from the stream.
    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
    lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
    lines so far exceeds hint.
    """
    if hint is None or hint <= 0:
        return list(self)
    n = 0
    lines = []
    for line in self:
        lines.append(line)
        n += len(line)
        if n >= hint:
            break
    return lines
```

It's *appending* each line it reads - which share same mechanics for `readline` - it's not loading up entire file at all.

This is also same for C implementation `iobase.c`:

```
while (1) {
    Py_ssize_t line_length;
    PyObject *line = PyIter_Next(it);
    if (line == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            goto error;
        }
        else
            break; /* StopIteration raised */
    }

    if (PyList_Append(result, line) < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(line);
        goto error;
    }
    line_length = PyObject_Size(line);
    Py_DECREF(line);
    if (line_length < 0) {
        goto error;
    }
    if (line_length > hint - length)
        break;
    length += line_length;
}
```

As you see it's calling `PyList_Append` to append results to list.

---

P.S. Just a reminder, joining is half bad as concatenating for this many strings, use `print` with `sep`, `file` parameter is recommended. Do not join strings where it's not needed.

Comment: This is what im looking for. So from here we can say for the seeking of performance only, we should always use readline in Python?

Comment: For performance aspect, as you see, use of ```iter(f.readline, '')``` in for loop is fastest - but this violates zen - *Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules* - by iterating non-iterator via ```iter``` hack. Just tested on *pypy3.6* and I can clearly say there is no faster way unless using ```C``` implementation.

Comment: Even in ```readlines``` document it says *You can iterate using ```readline``` in first place without ```readlines```.* So I suspect it's backward-compatibility or something.

Answer (score 0):

`Readlines` reads all the text into memory before starting the loop, while `readline` just reads a buffer at a time, automatically, while looping.
[Here's](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html?m=1) a better explanation of the memory comparison between the two.