# Why is the sequential code faster than the multithreaded code?

Tags: python, multithreading

Why does the sequential code run faster than the multithreaded code?

```py
import time
import math
import threading

def run(i):
    i = i * math.pi
    return i**2

def run2(i, j, l):
    for x in range(i, j):
        l.append((x*math.pi)**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tm = time.time()
    # Sequential
    res = [run(i) for i in range(20000)]
    print(time.time() - tm)
   
    tm = time.time()
    # Multithreaded
    n = 24 # Number of threads
    ans = []
    t = 20000
    for i in range(n - 1):
        ans.append([])
        tp = threading.Thread(target=run2, args=(round(t//n*i), round(t//n*(i+1)), ans[len(ans) - 1]))
        tp.start()
    ans.append([])
    tp = threading.Thread(target=run2, args=(round(t//n*n), t, ans[len(ans) - 1]))
    tp.start()
    
    print(time.time() - tm)
```

It seems that for non intensive tasks the sequential is faster. Any ideas why and how could the multithreaded version be sped up?

Comment: One reason is that the Python interpreter is largely bottlenecked around a single mutex so that only one thread can be interpreting bytecode at a time.  Google “Python GIL” for details.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I've heard about it, so I tried using `multiprocessing` instead but I get the same result

Comment: The two sections of code are completely different, so any performance comparisons between them are totally meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to GIL a python interpreter can't run more than one python code at any given time.

But, other than that, You're `appending` to list.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def appending():
...     output = []
...     for i in range(1000000):
...         output.append(i)
...     return output
... 
>>> def gen_exp():
...     return [i for i in range(1000000)]

>>> print(f"{timeit.timeit(appending, number=100):.2}")
8.1

>>> print(f"{timeit.timeit(gen_exp, number=100):.2}")
5.2
```

This slow nature of appending to the `list` is best shown on [readline/readlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072842) performance differances.

Without those, normally time-benchmarking would be simplified as following.

```py
import math
import timeit
from concurrent import futures
import multiprocessing


def run(i):
    i = i * math.pi
    return i ** 2


def wrapper_sequential():
    return [run(i) for i in range(20000)]


def wrapper_thread_pool():
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exc:
        fut = [exc.submit(run, i) for i in range(20000)]
        output = [f.result() for f in fut]

    return output


def wrapper_multiprocess():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
        output = pool.map(run, (i for i in range(20000)))

    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Thr: {timeit.timeit(wrapper_thread_pool, number=10):.4}")
    print(f"Seq: {timeit.timeit(wrapper_sequential, number=10):.4}")
    print(f"Mlt: {timeit.timeit(wrapper_multiprocess, number=10):.4}")
```

```
Thr: 5.146
Seq: 0.05411
Mlt: 4.055
```

Cost to create `thread` is just not worth as GIL only allows a python interpreter single python code at any given moment.

For `Multiprocessing`, as there is no direct way for python interpreter to communicate over processes, internally `pickle` is used to serialize data for inter-process communications - this is overhead.

If calculation is heavy enough, `Multiprocessing` will eventually overcome that overhead and starts getting ahead of sequential, but `thread` will never.

Comment: Is that a problem only in Python? If I need to speed up calculations that are not heavy enough, do I have to use another language, and if so, which one would be a good choice?

Comment: No, when calculating things with absolutely no *IO* involved, ```thread``` will never get faster than sequential in any language. As I mentioned, ```thread``` is costly, and a process can only use one cpu. With that limited CPU resource you're wasting it with creating, maintaining, communicating and switching ```thread```s without any benefit.

Comment: ```thread``` is meant for IO bottleneck. If interpreter sits in for IO - printing, reading, writing, waiting etc - GIL is released and interpreter starts running code in another thread and this is concurrency. ```Multiprocessing``` is more suitable for mere calculations without any IO calls. [Refer this](https://books.google.co.kr/books?redir_esc=y&hl=ko&id=bIZHCgAAQBAJ&q=GIL#v=snippet&q=GIL&f=false).

Comment: yes, I mean for no I/O intensive tasks. In that case, which language will be more appropriate, since `multiprocessing` is too slow in Python?

Comment: Go for somewhat lower levels, C++, C, or even lower, assembly. But my recommendation is attaching C codes to CPython. ```numpy```, ```pandas``` are fast because those are a module written in C.

Comment: I did a test in C++ and Java and it seems to work alright. But writing it in Python will be great so I'll take a look at CPython

Comment: Python you're using is CPython - Official implementation of Python. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) for jump-starting.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look into it!